# Displaying an object stored in a view property (Ember.js)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, emblem.js

I have a view with several properties, including one that I want to contain an object. The view looks like this:

```
Whistlr.LightboxView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'lightbox'
  classNames: ['ember-lightbox']
  content: ""
```

`content` is the property I want to contain an object. I set the object like so:

```
lightbox = Ember.View.views[$(".ember-lightbox").attr('id')]
lightbox.set 'content', Whistlr.AuthRegisterView.create()
```

As far as I can tell, the object is setting correctly. However, when I try to display it like this:

```
#lightbox
  view.content
```

The browser displays this, instead:

```
<Whistlr.AuthRegisterView:ember364>
```

How can I get it to actually render the object, rather than a string representing the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a quirk in the way I was using Emblem.js. Typically, I can render views with a simple:

```
Whistlr.AuthRegisterView
```

However, in this case I had to explicitly state that I'm rendering a view, perhaps because the view has been transformed into a string. I can now get it working with:

```
view Whistlr.AuthRegisterView
```

or

```
view view.content
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior, because this is the default `toString` provided by `Ember.Object` the base class for all ember classes.

I recommend you to show each property that you want to be visible:

```
#lightbox
  view.content.login
  view.content.password
```

So when one of these properties change, the display view will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define your own toString method in this object